# Specto says "The network connection seems to be down"

Tags: networking, lubuntu

I just installed [Specto](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/specto) on Lubuntu 12.04. It shows the message

> The network connection seems to be down, network watchers will not check until then.

What should I do?

My network connection is not down.

Comment: Bug report on Launchpad: [Sync with upstream version 0.4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/specto/+bug/816320/) -- But regport on Specto’s tracker: [Specto always thinks it's offline with NetworkManager 0.9](https://code.google.com/p/specto/issues/detail?id=327)

Answer (score 0):

comment out some lines in /usr/share/pyshared/spectlib/watch.py

```
def check_connection(self):
if not self.specto.connection_manager.connected():
self.specto.logger.log(_(“No network connection detected”), “warning”, self.name)
self.specto.connection_manager.add_callback(self.start_checking)
self.specto.mark_watch_status(“no-network”, self.id)
return False
else:
self.specto.mark_watch_status(“idle”, self.id)
return True
```

to

```
def check_connection(self):
# if not self.specto.connection_manager.connected():
# self.specto.logger.log(_(“No network connection detected”), “warning”, self.name)
# self.specto.connection_manager.add_callback(self.start_checking)
# self.specto.mark_watch_status(“no-network”, self.id)
# return False
# else:
self.specto.mark_watch_status(“idle”, self.id)
return True
```

source: http://www.produnis.de/blog/?p=1916

Or use urlwatch